# escape double quotes in a variable when using echo|set /p=

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, double-quotes

`echo|set /p=` can output a variable without a newline.

I am trying to loop a text file like this

```
for /f %%a in (zen.txt) do (
    set var=%%a
    echo !var!
    echo|set /p=!var!
)
```

There are some lines with only one `"`, for example:

```
"he said...
```

`echo` outputs the line like above correctly while `echo|set /p=` output nothing.

Is it possible to escape double quotes in a variable when using `echo|set /p=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will need to provide `set/p` with additional quotes to consume. You can try with something like (without the test file creation, of course)

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem TESTING - Create a input file
    >zen.txt (
        echo "He said...
        echo It was not me!
        echo It was "the thing"!
        echo ...
        echo ^& it was all"  ( The end )
    )

    for /f "delims=" %%a in (zen.txt) do (
        <nul set /p="%%a "
    )
```

`echo|set /p` simulates a return key press to terminate the `set/p` prompt, but it creates separate `cmd` instances for each side of the pipe making it slow. A `<nul` input redirection is enough to get the same result but faster and with less resources usage.

Answer (score 3):

`set /p` is a bit nasty with handling whitespaces, quotes and equal signs.

A quote at the beginning or the end has to be doubled, BUT when you want to display quotes, the expression should be enclosed in quotes, too.

To display a single quote use

```
<nul set /p ="""
```

`set /p` seems to strip one time the outer quotes.

Your code can be changed to `<NUL set /p="!var!"` that should work with normal text and also with quotes.

If the text starts with whitespaces, they will be dropped. (But not up to XP, there `set /p "=   Hello"` shows the spaces).

`set /p` seems to use two times a quote remover.
First for the extended set syntax
`<nul set /p "=hello" Text after the last quote will be dropped`

But also for the content, the outer quotes will be dropped
`<nul set /p ="hello" Text after the last quote will be dropped`

And even combining both works
`<nul set /p "="hello" Text after the last inner quote will be dropped "`

Note: I use `<nul set /p`, it's much faster, because the `echo | set /p` version uses a pipe and spawns two new cmd.exe instances. (Already mentioned by MC ND)

Comment: +1, When I could I will take a look on how it is handled, but I think the *"two time quote remover"* involves the `cmd` parser followed by the `set/p` parser.

Comment: @MCND I don't think it's the cmd parser, as the quote handling should all be done only by the `set` command itself

Comment: Checked and you are right. `cmd` parser passes everything to the `set/p` parser. The `set /p` parser removes the quotes in several steps. While locating variable name initial and tailing (if initial present) quotes are removed. While locating prompt literal same operation is done.

Comment: And by remove (in both cases) I mean move starting pointer for initial quote, replace last quote with `0x00`,  the reason why in `set /p "=hello" text` the `text` literal dissapears.